# Appending Elements to an Existing List in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, append, scheme

I need some help understanding the syntax on how to append a number into a list, i'm doing this from user input via the console so this elements have to be entered in recursively. So for ever number that is entered, the list must grow for each element (only numbers) added.

Here is the code I am working with, the problem lies in the second conditional. Right now this works but only creates an empty list of each number I put in, so the results would be

```
 >12
 >202
 >30
 ()()()
 zero input: stopping list


(define (inputlist)
(let ((applist list))
(let ((inpt (read)))
  (cond
  ((= inpt 0)(newline) (display "zero input: stopping list"))
  ;;OLD((number? inpt) (cons inpt applist) (display (applist))(inputlist))
  ((number? inpt) (append (applist)(list inpt)) (display (applist))(inputlist))
  (else 
  display "Not a number")))))
```

I understand why cons is not doing what I need it to be doing, but is there a similar functionality to appending each read in element to a pre-existing list?

EDIT: I've gotten closer what i've needed to do but still with the same results, i am now appending upon my applist with a list i create via every input, though it is still resulting in as many empty lists as I input.

SECOND EDIT: I've realized why it's printing multiple ()'s is because it's being called off the stack when 0 is entered, so i'm sure it's not working because the appending isn't working as intended, i've displayed the applist on the 0 conditional and it returns one null list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to append an element to the end of a list while looping would be to do call `append` and update the reference to the list afterwards:

```
(set! applist (append applist (list inpt)))
```

Notice that you have several misplaced parentheses - in your code some are missing, some are unnecessary. In Scheme `()` means *function application*, and you have to be careful where you put those brackets.

Also, be aware that `append` doesn't modify the initial list, it creates a new one, and if you need to refer to it, you have to store it somewhere (that's why I'm doing a `set!` above).

There are more serious errors with you logic. The conditions are in the wrong order (you have to test if the input is a number before asking if it's zero), and you forgot to loop if something other than a number is entered. Also, if we pass along the list as a parameter to the loop, we won't have to do an ugly `set!`. Try this instead, it's closer to what you were aiming for:

```
(define (inputlist)
  (let loop ((applist '()))
    (let ((inpt (read)))
      (cond ((not (number? inpt))
             (display "not a number")
             (newline)
             (loop applist))
            ((zero? inpt)
             (display "zero input: stopping list"))
            (else
             (let ((new-applist (append applist (list inpt))))
               (display new-applist)
               (newline)
               (loop new-applist)))))))
```

As mentioned in the comments, bear in mind that appending at the end of a list inside a loop in general is a bad idea. It's ok for learning purposes, but in real-life code, you'd `cons` at the head of the list and `reverse` it at the end - this is more efficient.

Comment: If I don't have brackets around applist, i'm getting thrown errors because inpt and applist aren't of the same time, or at least one of them is getting called as <subr list>

Comment: So in other words i've been having trouble with understanding exactly what i'm casting when i'm calling a variable or list, i've been getting this error for of <subr #> be it list or read or what have you, is this due to the over excessive parenthesis? What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: @James I updated my answer with a correct solution, but you have to spend more time reading a tutorial and the documentation, you still have trouble with some basic concepts.

Comment: What tutorial would you recommend?

Comment: @James also, the weird type errors you were getting stemmed from the fact that you were initializing `applist` with the `list` _procedure_, without actually _calling it_. An empty list is created by writing `(list)` or `'()`.

Comment: @James "The Little Schemer", "How to Design Programs" are great books to start with, or for more advanced stuff, "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" is the best reference for learning Scheme.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It's probably a good idea to mention that using `(append lst (list x))` in a loop is, in general, an antipattern, and that the better pattern is to use `(cons x lst)` in the loop and reverse afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `(cons x xs)` where x is an element and xs is a list produces a new list which has x as its first element.

Here is one way to use cons to add an element in the end of a list:

Example:
    Add 4 to (1 2 3)
    1. Reverse the list:    (3 2 1)
    2. Add 4 to the front:  (4 3 2 1)
    3. Reverse:             (1 2 3 4)

```
> (reverse (cons 4 (reverse (list 1 2 3)))
(1 2 3 4)
```

A function that uses this principle:

```
(define (cons-to-back x xs)
  (reverse (cons x (reverse xs))))

> (cons-to-back 4 (list 1 2 3))
(1 2 3 4)
```

An alternative is to use `append` which appends the elements of two lists:

```
> (append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

All we need to do, is to the the element into a list before using append:

```
> (append '(1 2 3) (list 4))
'(1 2 3 4)
```

Alternative definition of `cons-to-back`:

```
(define (cons-to-back x xs)
  (append xs (list x)))
```